# Using the same div to show different videos on click

Tags: html, css, iframe, css-transitions

I am trying to display different videos within the same Div when the user clicks a certain link.

I have made it work in JSFiddle, but when I upload it to my site it isn't changing videos on click like on fiddle. Also the container I am using to hold the video's isn't showing up until a link is clicked. I need the container to constantly be on the page.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BeSafer/nhx8frku/3/

The website where you can see the functionality on my page is http://www.besafer.org, under the `videos` section.

```css
table~div[id] {
  display: none;
}

div[id]:target {
  display: block;
}

#education {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://www.howlinwolfmedia.com/galleryphotography /Computer1.png) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  padding: 3% 13.7% 17.2% 16.9%;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="fireplace">
  <div id="computer" style='position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0px; padding-bottom: 60%;'>
    <iframe id="education" style='position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YXMkXsy-dx4?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="candle">
  <div id="computer" style='position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0px; padding-bottom: 60%;'>
    <iframe id="education" style='position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/IfuSO6cMPYM?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple repeated #ids which will always force a "lazy" find in DOM. Having more than one element that has `id='education'` and `id='computer'` is invalid and detrimental to basic behavior and performance. Once an #id is found, the browser no longer looks for anything else because the browser ***will always assume that an #id is unique -- therefore it's illogical to continue trying to find another element with the same #id.***

You don't even need JavaScript, you can use a very old feature of `<a>`.

1. One iframe with YT video embeded. Set a `name`

   - Ex. `<iframe` **name='yt'** `...`
2. For each video assign an `<a>`. Set each one a URL of a video as the `href`

   - Ex. `<a` **href='https://www.youtube.com/embed/YXMkXsy-dx4?rel=0&showinfo=0'** `>Grilling</a>`
3. Next set each `<a>` `target` attribute to the `name` attribute of the iframe

   - Ex. `<a href='https://www.youtube.com/embed/YXMkXsy-dx4?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0'` **target='yt'** `>Grilling</a>`

### Demo

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href='https://www.youtube.com/embed/YXMkXsy-dx4?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0' target='yt'>Fireplace</a>

  <a href='https://www.youtube.com/embed/tbPKVMpEA6M?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0' target='yt'>Electrical</a>

  <a href='https://www.youtube.com/embed/JKxEGq_u6cM?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0' target='yt'>Smoking</a>
</nav>

<iframe name='yt' style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 30px; width: 50%; min-height: 50%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C9KSFRq4rXA?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: No problem, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what logical approach you've tried to use here, having lots of repeating elements. But refactoring your original code, you can achieve what you want by using one div with iframe that is always visible, and javascript to change its src property (therefore changing the video inside)

script

```
function playVideo(id)
{
    document.getElementById('education').src = id;
}
```

html (just keep one of these divs)

```
<div id="computer" style='position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0px; padding-bottom: 60%;'>
    <iframe id="education" style='position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%' src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
```

add onclick=playvideo(videolink) for every link in the list

```
<a href="#" onclick='playVideo("https://www.youtube.com/embed/tbPKVMpEA6M?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0")'>
                electrical
              </a>
```

and remove this line from css

```
table ~div[id] {
  display: none;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhx8frku/6/)